# import record of fraction of seconds into postgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

There is one csv file & in one column datetime column value is in nano second (i.e. 21/11/2021 01:00:05.120972944). I need to insert csv file data into postgreSQL database. When i used datetime column datatype `timestamp(6)` then throwing error invalid syntax of datetime column. What would be correct datatype of datetime column in potgreSQL database.

Comment: "*invalid syntax of datetime column*" - is not a Postgres error message. `timestamp` is the correct data type for a "date and time" column (or maybe `timestamp with time zone`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i tried using `timestamp with time zone` as well but again getting invalid syntax error.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete SQL statement you are using (as formatted text, no screen shots please) and the complete and exact error message you get. ("*invalid syntax of datetime column*" is not a Postgres error message.

Comment: If after fixing the type, you are still getting an error, but a different one, then you need to share the new error with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum precision for a timestamp is 6. You're providing data with a precision of 9.

```
laetitia=# select now()::timestamp(9);
WARNING:  TIMESTAMP(9) precision reduced to maximum allowed, 6
LINE 1: select now()::timestamp(9);
                      ^
            now             
----------------------------
 2022-10-05 11:41:02.107602
(1 row)
```

So my suggestion is to add the data into a temporary table with this column as text and then transform it into a timestamp to insert it into your regular table. (Actually, when loading data from CSV files, I always suggest loading everything in a temporary table and then transforming it with SQL).

For example:

```
laetitia=# select col::timestamp(9)
from (values ('01/11/2021 01:00:05.120972944')) as test(col);
WARNING:  TIMESTAMP(9) precision reduced to maximum allowed, 6
LINE 1: select col::timestamp(9)
                    ^
            col             
----------------------------
 2021-01-11 01:00:05.120973
(1 row)
```

I guess the warning is acceptable in that case, or you can craft another query to avoid that warning too.

Oh, I almost forgot, make sure your date time default format is the right one because if Postgres wants MM/DD/YYYY, then the 21/11/2022 is out of range!

Comment: Thanks even i also know max 6 digit in fraction we can take but actual date column value in Nano second (9 fractional digit), so in this case how can we import data.

Comment: Then you can't using timestamp (with or without time zone).